# How to filter Lambda responses using attributes in SNS from destination?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Now that AWS Lambda supports sending responses directly to SNS without using the AWS API using the ['Destinations' feature](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/), is it possible to include message attributes in the response? In particular in order to do message filtering (e.g. via a subscription filter policy). Something like this:

`{ "Message" : "Hello World", "Accepted" : "true" }`

We want SNS to look at the `Accepted` field and forward the message to the next step if `true`. It looks like this should be possible but I can't find any docs on exactly how to specific the message attributes on a response payload when using a lambda destination rather than the AWS API.

How do we format the lambda response payload so that an SNS attribute filter can operate on it, for a Lambda Destination -> SNS message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In looking at the Lambda console and the Lambda documentation, I can't see a way to configure Lambda Destinations to include Message Attributes for Amazon SNS.

Instead, you could code the function itself to send a message to Amazon SNS, specifying the desired message attributes.

Comment: Is there another way to achieve what we want i.e. switching messaging on the payload without using attributes? (and without using the AWS API from inside the function). I'm aware we can add extra lambdas to call the API directly, or code the SNS call inside the lambda, i'm just curious of theres a supported infra way to do this.

Comment: No, there does not appear to be anything. What is your concern with calling SNS from the Lambda function?

Comment: Simply because it seems a little weird to wire up sns to sqs to lambda in aws then lambda to sns in code. It means the code is heavily tied into the Infra. But I suppose this isn't a big deal. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Now, SNS supports payload-based message filtering as well. Thus, you can filter the events coming from your Lambda functions. Check this out:  https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/11/amazon-sns-payload-based-message-filtering/